# Listings numbering doesn't restart

Tags: numbering, listings

I have problem with listing numbering from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134418/numbering-of-listings) topic. Numbering isn't restarted, it just continues.

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{%
    \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
      \thesection.\arabic{lstlisting}%
    \else
      \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
        \thesubsection.\arabic{lstlisting}%
      \else
        \thesubsubsection.\arabic{lstlisting}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }
}
```

For subsubsection 4.2.1 it should start from the beginning but it continues so I'm getting 4.2.1.2 (because there is one previous listing).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try `\counterwithin{lstlisting}{subsubsection}` from the [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/chngcntr/chngcntr.pdf) package. Does it help?

Comment: @LudovicC. The `chngcntr` command is `\counterwithin`.

Comment: @lockstep Thanks! When writing I thought it sounded weird `\numberwithin{}{}`. ;)

Comment: @LudovicC. this is the error that I'm getting now...

`Error: No counter 'lstlisting' defined.`

Do I include it in preamble or after document beginning?

Comment: Try to place it at the very end of your preamble.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's no different from what I already suggested you as answer to [Caption and sections, subsections and subsubsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132954/caption-and-sections-subsections-and-subsubsections)

The only addition is that `\AtBeginDocument` is necessary, because `listings` defines there the counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,chngcntr}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \counterwithin*{lstlisting}{section}
  \counterwithin*{lstlisting}{subsection}
  \counterwithin*{lstlisting}{subsubsection}
  \renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{%
    \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
      \thesection.\arabic{lstlisting}%
    \else
      \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
        \thesubsection.\arabic{lstlisting}%
      \else
        \thesubsubsection.\arabic{lstlisting}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Caption]
\caption{section.lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Caption]
\caption{subsection.lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Caption]
\caption{subsection.lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Caption]
\caption{subsubsection.lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Caption]
\caption{subsection.lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
\section{A section}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Caption]
\caption{section.lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this written anywhere in the `listings` documentation? I couldn't find mention of using `\AtBeginDocument` anywhere.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @kando I don't think you find any mention of this in the manual for `listings`. Why it defines the counter “at begin document” is something I can't explain without a deep study of the package code. I just discovered the fact and so adjusted the solution to do the relevant work “at begin document”.

Comment: Thank you for your tribal knowledge. I'd be lost without it. : j

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer thanks to link that @LudovicC. posted. Since all of my listings are in `subsubsections` I added this line of code in the preamble

`\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{subsubsection}}`

I don't think that it's right solution but it works in my case!

Comment: It's the right solution except you shouldn't need `\AtBeginDocument` so long as you place the counterwithin command after loading the listings and chngctr packages

Comment: If all your listings are at the same level you don't need the complicated if test in your question which is just to modify the format depending on  the level. You just want `\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{lstlisting}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `listings` defers defining `\newcounter{lstlisting}` at begin document.